# Handling Clojure project dependencies when dynamically linking to Clojure runtime from another JVM language?

Tags: scala, clojure, jvm, sbt, leiningen

I have two projects:

1. A `lein`-based Clojure project, with its own set of dependencies
2. A `sbt`-based Scala project, with its own set of dependencies

Initially, the Clojure project acted as a microservice, through HTTP, serving the main Scala process. Because of this setup, I could use a REPL-based workflow in the Clojure project, and be able to dynamically update the service during development, without having to restart the Scala project. This was a nice, efficient development setup.

Due to performance issues, we needed to remove the service-through-HTTP + serialization/deserialization overhead of the microservice, and so the main functionality of the Clojure project is now wrapped in a `(gen-class ..)` function that compiles the service boundary into a class `Engine`. The Clojure project is then compiled into an `uberjar` and copied into the Scala project directory system, which the project automatically imports into the classpath.

While this system is performant, the development experience has severely degraded, as the system must be recompiled, and totally restarted between changes.

**I'd like to re-capture the REPL-based workflow, but I am not sure how to handle the dependencies of the Clojure `lein`-based project.**

I know that I can import the Clojure runtime from Scala, as it is a JVM language, and I just need to use roughly the same Java calls. However, I am not sure how to appropriately handle the dependencies within the Clojure code. Do I need to import them from the `sbt` side?

Ultimately, my question can be summarizes as so:
**Given two separate projects, one `sbt`-based (Scala), and one `lein`-based (Clojure), how can I dynamically link the Clojure project from Scala, including the dependencies of the Clojure project, in such a way to maintain a REPL-based development environment for the Clojure part of the system, to prevent whole-stack application restarts?**

Comment: I don't have a answer to your question, although this idea may come in handy: https://blog.michielborkent.nl/blog/2016/07/26/clojure-from-scala/